# как в цикле вывести значение последним

Tags: python-3.x

как в цикле вывести последним значение переменной, допустим n = 5, выводило 4, 3, 2, 1 а потом 5?

```
n = 5
while n > 0:
    print(n)
    n -= 1
    if n == 1:
        print(n)
```

Comment: Проблема не понятна. Цикл у вас идет по убыванию n от 5 до 1. Если нужно вывести 5 в конце - выведите его после цикла.

Comment: while что то там:
print(n)
так?

Comment: В конце просто добавьте print(5) без отступов.